# Format of hashed strings

Tags: hash, sha2

When hashing a string, sometimes I see the format like so:

`{SHA512}1G2zjh2Bso/LzS06JDLXcELCJX4TQm7oXL5Et3Yg4Veyji7iQW26VnBdEHiURM5evO6duJjzY5387mkWV0oiyYA=`

Specifically the section indicating the hash function `SHA512`.

Is this a standard? Is there some documentation somewhere on what the possible values between `{}` can be?

For example, if I wanted to use bcrypt, what would I put there?

Comment: Where do you see this?  There's no context at all to this question.  Hash storage is generally application specific.

Comment: That's basically what I'm asking, if is this a standard.

Comment: I have never seen this format. Please indicate *where you saw this* so that the community could possibly help you out.

Comment: That pretty much answers my question, it's not a standard, so it doesn't really matter where it came from.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange for Security.  You can take a tour by clicking here   http://security.stackexchange.com/tour  It will explain how Stack Exchange works.  Thanks for your contribution and again, welcome.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard, it is implementation-specific. It's used by the library which hashes the password to identify which hash function have been used.

For example, PHP use this format in its [password hashing library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php):

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

- `2y` means that PHP used the bcrypt algorithm.
- `10` is the cost used to hash the string.
- The rest of the string stores the salt (if used), and the hash itself.

Having these metadata allows PHP to automatically select the correct algorithm / cost when the script calls [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) with the user-supplied string.

Comment: This is the "crypt" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29 format aka "modular crypt format" used by many many things on Unix as well as PHP and Perl and more.